# Postgres Pro: как подружить plsh с Postgres Pro?

Tags: postgresql, установка, расширения

При установке расширения **plsh** выходит ошибка. Делов том, что **plsh** не "видит" установленного **Postgres Pro**, он "заточен" только под опенсорсный **PostgreSQL**. Вопрос, как скомпилировать, при компилации что править чтобы подружить **plsh** не с опенсорсным **Postgres Pro:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для установки вам понадобятся:

- исходники [plsh](https://github.com/petere/plsh)
- пакеты для разработки (`-devel`) от Postgres Pro, т.к. вам нужны подключаемые файлы.

Процедура установки типичная для расширений Postgres-а и описана в README `plsh` по ссылке выше.

Comment: 1. Где скачать Postgres Pro Dev? Поделитесь пожалуйста ссылкой на описание. 2. В исходнике plsh перед компиляцией править ничего не надо? Спасибо заранее!

Comment: @Seomat вы пользуетесь дистрибутивом, очевидно, вы где-то его получили. Как и где скачать этот пакет я не подскажу, этим продуктом пользоваться не доводилось.
В исходниках ничего менять не надо.